# What can Shardminds do instead of sleep?

Tags: dnd-4e

In D&D 4e, a Shardmind does not require sleep, but do need to rest. It is my understanding that this means that during an extended rest they can engage in non-strenuous activities. What are the rules for deciding what activities are and are not applicable?

From the compendium....

> They don’t need sleep, though they must still rest for six hours to gain the benefits of an extended rest.

Comment: The rule says non-strenuous, so whatever the DM and players agree upon. It's open-ended by design.

Comment: I posted this as an answer, but I agree with Wax Eagle that it seems more like a comment, so here is it's new home:
I ran a short campaign where one of my players was a Shardmind. When he slept he would essentially "shut down" and stop moving in place, becoming a statue. He could still perceive things happening around him, but coming out of this powered down state would interrupt the rest cycle. It often freaked out the NPCs that were unfamiliar with what shardminds were.

Comment: @okeefe Do you know the source of that rule? I've been going off hearsay.

Comment: @madrius that is highly amusing.

Comment: @user2525 Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Player's Handbook 1, page 263*
>
> **No Strenuous Activity:** You normally sleep during an extended rest, though you don't have to. You can engage in light activity that doesn't require much exertion.

A shardmind can engage in any activity that everyone agrees is light.

Comment: Other than my question, is there any link between Shardmind's sleeping patterns and the above? Is there a construct-wide ruling?

Comment: As per the Rules Compendium page 310, constructs are not living creatures and don't need to sleep (or breathe, or eat). However, shardminds are Living Constructs (PH3 page 12), but it states there they they don't need to eat, drink, breathe, or sleep.  So, the lack of sleep seems to be from their construct nature, but the need for rest seems like an aspect of  being living. (And balance for being a player race.)

Comment: Okay, so 4e decouples sleep and extended rest. For some reason I was missing that before, that was the missing link for me. Thank you for your great answer.